# Using Between Command in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table

```
drink_name........cost........calories

Black.............1...........30

Clue..............2...........40

Elephant----------3...........50
```

When I use the **between** command for characters (it excludes ending positions)

```
select drink_name from drink_info where drink_name between 'B' and 'C';

output:
Black
```

Note that Clue is omitted.

Now when using **between** for number comparison (it includes the ending position)

```
select drink_name from drink_info where cost between 1 and 3

Output:

1
2
3
```

Note that 3 is included.

Why is there a behaviour difference of the **between** keyword between integer and characters, because it includes the last number (3) whereas last character (Clue) is excluded

Comment: between matches values exactly - not just the first character.  Check into like which allows wildcards.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah even without using wild cards ,its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between works in exactly the same way in both cases.  It include both end points.

The difference is in how integers differ from strings (and floats and datetimes).

For this reason, it is often better to use `<` for the second comparison:

```
select drink_name
from drink_info
where drink_name >= 'b' and drink_name < 'c';
```

This will not include `'c'`.  If the second comparison were `<=` then `'c'` would be included, but nothing else that begins with `'c'`.

Comment: ,If it matches both endpoints ,then the output of Strings must be "Black and Clue" right ,but only "Black" is the output. but if u can ,explain me whats the reason for this to happen

Comment: @VijayIndia Gordon already explained that `b < ba < black < c < ca < canyletters` so you can do experiment `BETWEEN 'b' AND 'cz'` just to understand which values are greater than and which are less than

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose drink names with a beginning character between B and C inclusive:

select drink_name from drink_info where left(drink_name, 1) between 'B' and 'C';

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because of the characters following 'C'. To test it out create a drink name in your table called 'C' and execute your query and the output will have C in it.

When you used Between against integer field, you specify the whole integer (and not part of it) and hence you got the result including it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another variant to achieve your goal:

```
SELECT drink_name 
FROM drink_info 
WHERE LEFT(drink_name,1) BETWEEN 'B' and 'C';
```